# Retrieving words with 3 or less characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, metaphone

I have a table with a field that contains a bunch of neighborhood names. Some of these neighborhoods have names with 2 or more words. How can I get a list of words that are 3 or less characters and occur in the middle of name with 3 or more words?

For example:

*Lake* **=** Do nothing, only 1 word 
*Golden Lake* **=** Do nothing, only 2 words 
*Lakes of Gold* **=** Extract "of"

In essence I want to make a list of 'garbage' words to remove when I build metaphone sentences.

Comment: This will be difficult in MySQL. Its regex implementation only allows selecting rows where a certain field matches a certain regex. So you can't extract parts of a field to generate a new list in MySQL. And even if you could, you'd need lookaround to do exactly what you want, and POSIX regexes don't support that, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  'Lake of gold' RLIKE '[[:<:]].+[[:>:]].+[[:<:]].{1,3}[[:>:]].+[[:<:]].+[[:>:]]'
```

Unfortunately, `MySQL` can only match the regexps, not extract the patterns. You will have to do the filtering in `MySQL` and extraction on the script side.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP "[[:alnum:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]]{1,3}[[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]]+";
```

will find all entries that contain at least one word of up to 3 characters in between two other words.

You can't extract the words in MySQL directly, but this will filter the relevant rows. You have to do the extraction in a separate step.